# Lost connection with ssh server through web console ssh (GCP, Putty, gcloud terminal, Filezilla)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, public-key, private-key

After a year using the VM instance in debian, we changed the ssh keys to connect to other computers, after having generated the pair of public and private keys with putty, and adding it to the metadata, we configured the filezilla and accessed the instance's fpt, but after about two hours we lost the connection to the server through port 22. Connection error occurs, "`the server closed connection unexpectedly`". Also with the GCP web access by SSH, the error is as follows:

> An error has occurred during the communication with the SSH server
>   Check the configuration of the server and the network.
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaZ5q.jpg)

[image]

We have generated keys again and updated the metadata, we have tried to access through the gcloud terminal, and the error is the same. The firewall is activated to allow traffic through port 22.

Please any help on this error that you can give me, I will thank you very much. regard senter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Try to SSH to the instance with the following flag to get debugging messages during the SSH process.

```
gcloud compute ssh <YOUR-INSTANCE-NAME> --zone <YOUR-INSTANCE-ZONE> --ssh-flag="-vvv"
```

As there are many reasons this could happen,I suggest you to take a look at these [tips](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) to troubleshoot and resolve common SSH issues.